# Calling async Soap Webservice using Spring WebserviceTemplate which does not contain any response

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, spring-ws, webservicetemplate

I am calling ayncronus web service using WebserviceTemplate which does not return any response it only responds with 202 Accepted.
I call using 
wsTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(profileRequest, new WebServiceMessageCallback() {
....
}

I am receiving error SAAJ0511: Unable to create envelope from given source.
I suspect Client is expecting a SOAP XML response, but called WS does not return any response hence it is not able to unmarshal XML to java, hence this error is coming.
Can any one explain how to resolve this?
How to call a ayncronus web service which does not return any response only it is Accepted with 202 http response, using WebserviceTemplate